# General Python UI help

Tags: python, operator, panel

Ok, I've looked all over the place and I'm really stuck. I would like to have a panel with some input variables (like height and radius), which can be typed in. Then I would like a button that, when pushed, executes some python code (like creating a cylinder, moving it, put material on some of the vertices etc.)

But it seems that variables and buttons need to be hooked up to specific operators, so I lose control over the input variables. Maybe I'm thinking too much like Visual Studios forms. I could really use help.

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/116043/discussion-on-question-by-drdress-general-python-ui-help).